# Why is There a Hang Man Game Error "Too many values to unpack" Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a hang man game without YouTube and I have been stuck on this error for a while.

If you can see the error please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alfre\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Coin flip.py", line 4, in <module>
    for k, v in dictonary:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

At first I tried changing the long list to a python file:

```
from words import words
```

But it that does not work either.

I also tried lowering the number of words but that also did not work.

Current code:

```
import random
from words import words 

# set up
hang_man = []
lose_game = \
    ['''  O
         /|\ 
          |
         / \ ''']
stage_1 = \
    [''' O
            
          
            ''']
stage_2 = \
    ['''  O
         /|\ 
           
             ''']
stage_3 = \
    ['''  O
         /|\ 
          |
             ''']
stage_4 = \
    ['''  O
         /|\ 
          |
         / \ ''']

scale = 0

# random word
def random_word():
    return random.choice(words)

# actions
def word_action(player_pick):
    if player_pick == random_word():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def letter_action(player_choice):
    if player_choice in random_word():
        return True
    else:
        return False
# update
def update_hangman(scale1):

    if scale1 == 0:
        hang_man = stage_1[:]
        print(stage_1)
        scale1 = scale1 + 1
    elif scale1 == 1:
        hang_man = stage_2[:]
        print(stage_2)
        scale1 = scale1 + 1
    elif scale1 == 2:
        hang_man = stage_3[:]
        print(stage_3)
        scale1 = scale1 + 1
    elif scale1 == 3:
        hang_man = stage_4[:]
        print(stage_4)
        print('Sorry you lost')
        quit()
    return scale1


# main
def main():
    while True:
        print('Hang Man Game')
        user = input('''We have our word.
    Guess a letter or a word:'''.strip)
        if len(user) == 1:
            if letter_action(user) == True:
                pass
            else:
                pass
        elif len(user) > 1:
            if word_action(user) == True:
                print('That is the correct word.')
                print('Good job you win.')
                quit()
            else:
                update_hangman(scale)
                print('Sorry that was the wrong word')
                print('Try again')

        elif user == int:
            print('Please type a letter.')
        else:
            print('Please retype.')
```

And the list of words I used is:

```
words = ["aback","abaft","abandoned","..."]  # and many more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: try this `for k, v in dictionary.items():`

Comment: Yes, but isn't that related to dictionarys im using lists.